# MediaElement won't show PNG Opacity

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I cannot get a Media Element to show the opacity variations of a PNG image file. The sample PNG attached has several bands of RED (  R=255, G=0, B=0) with different levels of opacity. You can see the browser displays it correctly. But if I load it to a  Media Element, all the red bands show as solid RED (ie opacity alpha = 255). It is just a standard WPF Media Element. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: PNG with Opacity]

Comment: Why do you want to display images using `MediaElement`? `Image` class seems more useful for that.

Comment: @Fdooch, I want to apply pixel shaders to the image and the shaders work with media elements.

Comment: Sorry, i can't help here. All I know is that mediaelement couldn't even display transparent areas on video some time ago.

Comment: @Fdooch, I tried your suggestion. I tested this image adding it to a BitMap and displaying  with a PictureBox control. And that works fine. So it's not a problem with the image. It's the media element.